# how to check passwords on coincidence?

Tags: python, django

please help fix validation password change form.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^userprofile/password_page/$', 'views.password_page', name='password_page', ),        
url(r'^userprofile/password_page_changed/$', 'views.password_page_changed', ),
```

views.py:

```
@login_required 
def password_page(request):     
    if request.method == 'POST':                                
        form = ChangePasswordForm(data=request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = User.objects.get(username__exact=request.user.username)
            username.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
            username.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userprofile/password_page_changed/')                      
    else:                       
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request=request)
                
    t = loader.get_template('password_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
                                    'form': form,
    }, [custom_proc])   
    
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

forms.py:

```
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password_old = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(ChangePasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
    
    def clean_password_old(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password_old = cleaned_data.get("password_old") 
        if not self.request.user.check_password(password_old):
            raise forms.ValidationError("not true pass.")
        else:
            return password_old
    
    def clean(self):    
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")   
                
        if password1 != password2:      
            raise forms.ValidationError("not match.")
        else:                           
            return cleaned_data
```

password_page.html:

```
<form class="password_form common_form" action="{% url 'password_page' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <div class="cell">
        <label class="label">{{ form.password_old.label }}</label>
        
        {{ form.password_old }}
        
        {{ form.password_old.errors }}
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
        <label class="label">{{ form.password1.label }}</label>
        
        {{ form.password1 }}
        
        {{ form.password1.errors }}
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
        <label class="label">{{ form.password2.label }}</label>
        
        {{ form.password2 }}
        
        {{ form.password2.errors }}
    </div>      

    <div class="cell">
        <input class="submit btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Изменить" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

the problem is that when the user enters:

> password_old: qqq
> password1: q
>
> password2: qq

not as a result of a message indicating that the new password does 'not match'.

I need to type the different password1 and password2 display the error message validation 'not match'

Comment: I actually didn't understood the last 2 lines, can explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passwords don't match error is within the form.non_field_errors collection. You can access it via:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

If you want to have it display for a particular field, you can do the following. This will raise it for both the password fields.

```
raise ValidationError({
    'password1': ["Passwords must match.",],
    'password2': ["Passwords must match.",]
})
```